# MySQL performance of select a large set of data in a table

Tags: mysql, database, database-optimization

I have a question about MySQL optimization. Assume that there have a table `market_transition` with 1,000,000 data rows. Is there have any performance issue that if i do `SELECT * FROM market_transition WHERE end_time >= (SOME TIMESTAMP)` and it return 25,000?
In other words, is there have any performance problem that if a select statement have to return a large set of data?
if yes, how can it be optimized? Thank you for the help.

Comment: Possible duplication :

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4129071/optimal-mysql-settings-for-queries-that-deliver-large-amounts-of-data

Answer (score -1):

The issues may arise if you don't layout your indexes correctly.

Simply put:

1. use inno db engine
2. create indexes on the most used where condition columns

eg : where foo>1 and bar <1

Optimize by creating an index that combines both foo and bar columns.